# Stop Oracle from reading/modifying an object after modifying it in parallel

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to stop Oracle from executing in parallel when executing SQL queries for Airflow. Everything runs fine on our server that does not allow for parallel execution, but on a different server (where we actually need the program to run) it gets upset as parallel execution is allowed.

I have tried creating a trigger that executes ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL DML|DDL|QUERY every time the program creates a session to connect to the database but it still gives the following error:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Parallel/direct path inserts must be committed before you can query the new data. Parallel query is not the issue. Something is doing a parallel or direct path insert and not committing before attempting a query.

Comment: Can you post the code for your trigger? Are you sure it is executing?

Answer (score 0):

```
alter session set parallel_degree_policy=manual;
```

Have you set this parameter to manual?

And also you need to check/show these parameters:

```
select * 
from v$ses_optimizer_env e 
where e.sid=userenv('sid') 
and name like 'parallel%'
```

And have you checked your code that it doesn't enable parallel later?